# Inflar um aviso na view a partir de um BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

Tenho uma aplicação onde é necessário monitorar, e avisar o usuário quando ele estiver sem conexão disponível com a internet. Para resolver isso, criei um BroadcastReceiver e mostro um toast quando essa situação acontece. Porém eu preciso atualizar esta classe para que, ao invés de mostrar um toast, um TextView fique na tela informando o usuário que ele está sem conexão. Minha ideia é colocar um layout com esse TextView, sobre o layout atual na tela do usuário até que uma conexão esteja disponível, mas o problema é que eu não consigo fazer esta view ser exibida em qualquer tela que o usuário esteja.

Meu código do Bradcast está assim no momento:

```
public class Connectivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

Util util = new Util();
private ViewGroup mLinearLayout;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (!checkInternet(context)) {
        util.showToast(context, "Sem conexão disponível com a internet.", 1);
    }
}

boolean checkInternet(Context context) {
    ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager(context);
    if (serviceManager.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

E o layout que estou querendo inflar, está assim:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Sem conexão com internet disponível."
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#e01b18"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Como consigo, a partir de uma classe, mostrar esse aviso independente de qual tela ele esteja?

No final preciso que fique assim:

[image: Exemplo de como preciso que fique]

Comment: Uma possibilidade é usar um [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html).

Comment: O problema é que o AlertDialog não ficará na tela sempre, o usuário vai fechar, e não verá o aviso mais. A ideia é que a mensagem fique na tela, assim como na imagem que coloquei na edição.

Comment: Da pra fazer isso sim, tem várias formas,  uma que acho bem legal e útil de se aprender é usando a Lib Event Bus, ela cria comunicação entre entidades ou seja do seu Broadasct para sua activity ou service fragment em fim, estude qualquer coisa posso postar um trecho de código para você como resposta

Comment: Bacana! Eu estava meio perdido no que pesquisar para ajudar a resolver isso, com essa dica já vai ser bastante útil. Se puder postar esse código vai ser perfeito! Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não era da forma que eu esperava, mas este foi o melhor jeito que encontrei para fazer. Utilizei este post como base: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766739/show-an-alert-dialog-in-broadcast-receiver-after-a-system-reboot

Registrei um BroadcastReceiver dentro da minha activity:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
this.registerReceiver(Receiver, filter);
```

E criei o método que será responsável por fazer as alterações na view conforme as mudanças de conexão acontecem:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver Receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(!util.verificaConexao(context))
            msgPopUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            msgPopUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
};
```

Assim, o receiver funciona como deveria e as mensagens na view também.

Caso queira deixar mais organizado, como é o meu caso, pode criar uma classe. Com o código abaixo criei uma classe que ficaria responsável por registrar o broadcast e fazer as alterações na view

```
public class Broadcasts {
private TextView msgPopUp;
Util util = new Util();
View rootView;

public void registerBroadcastConnectivity(Context context, RelativeLayout mainLayout){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
    context.registerReceiver(Receiver, filter);

    rootView = ((Activity)context).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View menuLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notificacao_internet, mainLayout, true);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver Receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(msgPopUp == null)
            msgPopUp = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.popUpConexao);

        if(!util.verificaConexao(context)) {
            msgPopUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            msgPopUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
};
```

}

E abaixo é a instância do objeto, e a chamada para fazer o registro do broadcast passando o contexto e o layout da activity

```
 Broadcasts broadcast = new Broadcasts();
    broadcast.registerBroadcastConnectivity(this, (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.opcaoMesaLayout));
```

Com a classe acho mais elegante e organizado.